# System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem> How To Correct

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult UpdateBDDNBR(int? id)
{
    BillingDropDownNBReason billingDropDownNbReason = db.BillingDropDownNBReasons.Find(id);

    ViewBag.ListKey = new SelectList
        (db.BillingDropDownNBReasons.Where(x => x.Active == true),
        "ListKey", "ListValue");

    BillingDropDownNBReasonDataTablesViewModel billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm =
                new BillingDropDownNBReasonDataTablesViewModel();

    return View(billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm);
}


public ActionResult SecondUpdateBDDNBR(int? ListKeyid)
{
    if (ListKeyid == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    BillingDropDownNBReason billingDropDownNbReason = db.BillingDropDownNBReasons.Find(ListKeyid);
    BillingDropDownNBReasonDataTablesViewModel billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm = 
                new BillingDropDownNBReasonDataTablesViewModel();

    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.ListKey = billingDropDownNbReason.Listkey;
    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.ListValue = billingDropDownNbReason.ListValue;
    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.Description = billingDropDownNbReason.Description;
    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.Active = (bool) billingDropDownNbReason.Active;
    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.StartDate = billingDropDownNbReason.StartDate;
    billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm.EndDate = billingDropDownNbReason.EndDate;

    if (billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(billingDropDownNbReasonBDDNBRvm);
}
```

I am receiving the following error:

> System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'

newcomber to MVC.

I have a table looks Like:

```
ListKey, int, NonNull
ListValue, int, NonNull
Desc, String, Null
Active, Bool, Null
StartDate, DateTime
EndDate, DateTime
```

On button click i hit action UpdateBDDNBR() but I have no ListKey Id yet. So I send View bag back to view. Loads fine I use .js to hit the next action SecondUpdateBDDNBR() error occurs at this point. I am trying to return the values associated with the ListKet ID to a set of bound @html Helpers for update and eventually also a create area. Why do I get the error and how to write code with proper IEnumerable.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListKey").change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
        document.location.href = '/IOTDBBillingAdmin/SecondUpdateBDDNBR?ListKeyid=' + $(this).val();
    });
});

@Html.DropDownList("ListKey", Model.ListItems, ("--Select Reason--"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ListKey"})
```

Model

```
[Key]
public int? ListKey { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "List Value is Required")]
[StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "250 Charactors Max")]
public string ListValue { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListItems { get; set; }

public int? ListKeyid { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Description is Required")]
[StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "500 Charactors Max")]
public string Description { get; set; }

[Bindable(true)]
[SettingsBindableAttribute(true)]
public bool Active { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

public int RadioGroup { get; set; }
```

Comment: Its really hard to tell from this description. You should try describe what triggers the exception, like which request is made. Also give some context to each piece of code.

Comment: have you at least tried a google search on the error.. to see what it tells you in regards to explaining what the error means...

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag.ListKey appears to be a nullable int? here:

```
public int? ListKey { get; set; }
```

...but you are assigning a SelectList to it here:

```
ViewBag.ListKey = new SelectList
    (db.BillingDropDownNBReasons.Where(x => x.Active == true),
    "ListKey", "ListValue");
```

`SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` I believe which is the type mentioned in the exception.